# llamada desde angular a firestore

Tags: angular, firebase-storage

quiero eliminar datos de mi base de datos de firestore, pero, no entiendo por que no me deja, entiendo que yo estoy haciendo una llamada al id de mi collection de firestore, pero, no la elimina.

este es mi metodo

```
async deleteUser(user: usuario) {
    const userReg = doc(this.firestore, `crud/${user.id}`);
    await deleteDoc(userReg);
    console.log(userReg);
  }
```

este es mi html

```
   <mat-card class="card">
    <mat-card-content>
   
   <p>
      <mat-toolbar>
        <span>Usuarios</span>
<span class="example-spacer "></span>
<button routerLink="/crearusuario" mat-raised-button color="primary">Agregar</button>
      </mat-toolbar>
    </p>
    
    
    
    
  
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" #input>
    </mat-form-field>

      
    
    <div class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="listUser.length > 0">    
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >
        
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Username" >
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Username </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Username}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Name}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
      
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Lastname">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Lastname </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Lastname}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Sex">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sex </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Sex}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Action" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef ></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef style="text-align:right;">
              <a href="#">
                <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" style="color:black;" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="search" matTooltip="Search" aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"></mat-icon>
              </a>
              <a  style="color:red;" >
                <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" (click)="eliminarUsuario(listUser)" aria-label="Example home icon"  fontIcon="delete"  matTooltip="Delete" aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over" ></mat-icon>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" fontIcon="edit" matTooltip="Edit" aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip when focused or hovered over"></mat-icon>
              </a>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
            
            
          </tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
      </div>    
        <h2 *ngIf="listUser.length == 0" style="color:white;">
        no hay usuarios para mostrar
        </h2>
```

y este es mi component ts

async eliminarUsuario(user: any) {
const deleteUser = await this.fire.deleteUser(user);

```
this._snackBar.open('el usuario ya fue eliminado', '', {
  duration: 3000,
  horizontalPosition: 'center',
  verticalPosition: 'top',
});
```

}
}

no que no entiendo es por que no elimina el elemento, si yo me estoy dirigiendo bien a la direccion que deseo eliminar. yo vi un video en youtube y de ahi saque el metodo.

}